# Bessel equation of the first order has the solution $y=xJ_1(x)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am having trouble understating what this question actually want from me. I am about an hour in too revising this so I am very new, and thought it would be an idea to try and learn it through tacking a problem which is as follows.

> **Q:** Bessel Function of the first kind $J_n(x)$ are solutions of differential equations
>   $$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-n^2)y=0 \tag{1}$$
>   use this information to show that $y=xJ_1(x)$ is a solution of 
>   $$xy''-y'+xy=0 \tag{2}$$

So my thoughts are from what I have read I have to use the power series solution 'I think' but can seem to see how this gives me $xJ_1(x)$.

Also do I have to rearrange [2] in the form of [1]. My usual method of learning something new is to apply a equation of formula get a general idea of what going on then start to try a build more an intuition and to derive the formula from there.

But I have a feeling I cant quite apply this method to this, could someone maybe give some advice or even a link to a web site. All's that I seem to be getting at the moment are a lot of derivations and no application.

Also I have been told that I have to tick a box to say I am satisfied with my ans. But where is that box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$${{x}^{2}}y''+xy'+\left( {{x}^{2}}-{{n}^{2}} \right)y=0$$  where $$y={{J}_{n}}\left( x \right)$$ 
Consider now $u=xy$ and the DE
$$xu''-u'+xu=0$$ 
Substituting we have therefore
$$x\left( 2y'+xy'' \right)-\left( y+xy' \right)+x\left( xy \right)=0$$
Expanding and collecting 
$${{x}^{2}}y''+xy'+\left( {{x}^{2}}-1 \right)y=0$$
which is just Bessel’s equation for n=1, hence $u=x{{J}_{1}}\left( x \right)$ satisfies $xu''-u'+xu=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply plug in the solution

$$ y = xJ_1(x) $$
$$ y' = J_1(x) + x{J_1}'(x) $$
$$ y'' = 2{J_1}'(x) + x{J_1}''(x) $$

And then
$$ x(2{J_1}' + x{J_1}'') - (J_1 + x{J_1}') + x(xJ_1) = 0 $$

Or 
$$ x^2 {J_1}'' + x{J_1}' + (x^2-1)J_1 = 0 $$

This, of course, is Bessel's differential equation for $n=1$